# Error while compiling FIX protocol quickfix package

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, quickfix

I am trying to get the `quickfix` package installed on a Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS) with `python3`.
The code is taken from the quickfix [Github](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix.git).
Previous steps seems ok, but when I actually get to the `make` command I get this error:

```
QuickfixPython.cpp: In function 'PyObject* _wrap_ScreenLog_getMillisecondsInTimeStamp(PyObject*, PyObject*)':
QuickfixPython.cpp:252561:52: error: 'const class FIX::ScreenLog' has no member named 'getMillisecondsInTimeStamp'
    result = (bool)((FIX::ScreenLog const *)arg1)->getMillisecondsInTimeStamp();
                                                   ^
```

(there are additional three errors but with the same or very similar method issues)

Compiling without the `python` options ends successfully, and also with the `ruby` option is successful (and it uses the method `getMillisecondsInTimeStamp` that seems to be the issue).

This brings me to believe that the underline issue is connected to the header files or something similar.

Any and all ideas are welcome...